# Lighthouse Doesn't Know Font is Lazy-Loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse, webfont-loader

Lighthouse thinks my Roboto font load is blocking for over a second:

[image]

...but I'm loading Roboto with `webfontloader`:

```
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';

WebFont.load({
    google: {
        families: [
            'Roboto:300,400, 500',
        ],
    },
});
```

...and if I do an `empty cache and hard reload` and check my network tab, it appears to show the fonts being loaded very quickly:

[image]

Is there a way to get Lighthouse to detect that fonts are loaded in a non-blocking way?